# Using select() to choose between an existing client or a new client (C)

Tags: c, select, client, server

I am writing a small server/client program. I am not sure how to use `select()` to choose between a client that already is connected to the server, and to add a new client.

i.e.: The server program will start and be listening for clients. How can I use a select statement to know whether the server is receiving from an existing client, or a new connection?

Does the server always have to `listen()` and `accept()` every new client?

Thank you.

Comment: `select()` is not used to determine which client connected but instead, to determine among the connected clients which one can read/write without blocking. `listen()` takes a parameter that defines how many clients can be in the queue waiting for connection, `accept()` accepts the client and creates a new thread so you can wait for another client to be connected.

Comment: So how can I be selecting from connected clients while also listening for new clients that want to connect?

Comment: Do you have any code at all? something you have tried? otherwise this question is too broad and should be closed. Also, you can find good examples if you search on google.

Answer (score 0):

Before getting your hands dirty dealing with a selector you should read something about Non-Blocking I/O or asynchronous networking. Basically what your selector does is loop through the file descriptors that you have created and check whether someone wants to perform one of the following actions:

- Read
- Write
- Accept
- Connect

I could go further into how it does but if you really do want to know please do search into reactor pattern and maybe how programming through events work.

Anyway, to detect a new connection or an already existing one might be trivial or not so trivial, depending on how much control you want to have on the actions performed.

First. You register your server socket on the selector. This socket will stay listening forever and when a client connects the accept event will be triggered and one selector cycle will occur. This will create another file descriptor that you will have to register in your selector.

From this point forward you have to control your connection intention. Do you want to read? Write? Not only this, since this is asynchronous programming and you can't or should not block the information will have to be transferred in chunks. It will be up to you to receive all the data chunks and coordinate all the file descriptors. This is the non-trivial part.

If you want to know anything else please say so and i will edit this answer.